# Saving focal statistics in memory using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, in-memory, focal-statistics

I'm currently working on a project where I have written a script that is suppose to do several things. one of these is creating a "quick" focal statistics, from which I extract the values to some points. Afterwards I wont need the focal statistics output, so I was wondering if it was possible to save the output "in memory". Right now, each time I run:

```
        focalstats = arcpy.sa.FocalStatistics(inDSM, NbrCircle(7, "MAP"), "MINIMUM")
```

the line creates an output file called "FocalSt_dsm_x" (x is a number) in my environment workspace.

Of course, I could delete the file each time, but it seems a bit troublesome.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

Comment: Did you try setting env.workspace to in_memory? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166026/setting-in-memory-workspace-in-arcpy

Comment: Forget about it, it is temporary file, ArcGis will automatically delete.