# Euclidean distance raster fails with ArcPy script

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, in-memory

I am working on a script tool to create watersheds.
Part of my process requires a distance raster from various features that I use in an equation to perform local modifications to my DEM.

I have been unable to get arcpy.sa.EucDistance() to do anything when working with the in_memory workspace.

If I set the output to an FGDB it appears to work.

What am I missing to get this to work in_memory?

```
# convert vector points to raster points
# this output is successful
# I can do arcpy.CopyRaster_management(pp_ras, out_FGDB) and see 
# that in_memory\pp__ras looks like i expect.

arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(pourpoints, "OBJECTID",r"in_memory\pp__ras", dem) 
pp_ras = r"in_memory\pp__ras"  



# when I get to this part running in IDLE, the script just terminates with no
# pessages. If I print results from every step, the last one printed is me 
# setting teh pp_ras variable
# when I run from the script tool i'm building this into, the progressor gets 
# to "saving raster" and just  sits forever and I have to kill ArcMap/Catalog

euc_dist_in = arcpy.sa.EucDistance(r"in_memory\pp__ras", "", "", "", "")
euc_dist_in.save (r"in_memory\dist")
euc_dist = r"in_memory\dist"
```

Comment: Wrong use of tool, look at script example in help.

Comment: I'll happily admit to being an ameture, but don't see how I'm doing anything different from the example

Comment: Remove arcpy.sa and delete one of "'. The way you use it requires explicit declaration of output raster

Comment: Don't forget to import * from sa at the beginning.

Comment: appreciate the input. but just couldn't get it. ended up running it as arcpy.gp.EucDistance_sa(inSourceData, r"in_memory\eucdist_all", "", cellSize, "", "PLANAR")  it's probably not the cleanest or "correct way" but it's giving me the result I need and also appears to work with raster processing envi setting which helps me out too.  Definitely a topic to move up on list of things to learn more about.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default workspace setting to in_memory.  Something like this.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"in_memory"
```

Then change the names of your outputs to from  "in_memory\foo" to "foo"

[See this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166026/setting-in-memory-workspace-in-arcpy/166035).